# R: associating list elements to a LaTeX file

Tags: r, automation

I am implementing a factorial survey experiment in R and I need your help to increase the speed of survey implementation.

In factorial surveys, respondents are randomly assigned to a 'deck' of n scenarios, and respondents are asked to rate each scenario (or 'vignette'). Each scenario is composed by k dimensions, whose levels are randomly assigned; furthermore, to prevent anchoring effects, the order of the dimensions is random. R is perfect to define factor levels, creating combinations and combining string variables to express the various vignettes. In my experimental survey, I created a list file: each element of the list is a vector of factor levels, expressing the scenario. For example:

```
 $308
 [1] "Factor 1 - Level X"                                            
 [2] "Factor 4 - Level XX"                                 
 [3] "Factor 2 - Level X"                                                                                      
 [4] "Factor 3 - Level XXX"                     
 [5] "Factor 7 - Level XX"
 [6] "Factor 5 - Level X"                                                                                     
 [7] "Factor 6 - Level X"
```

To achieve a pleasant formatting of the vignettes, I also created a LaTeX template. The template includes a short (fixed) introduction of the scenario, a bullet list and a final statement.

I would like to know whether it is possible to associate each item of the bullet list to the various elements of the vector, within my list object. The "copy+paste" solution is unfeasible, over a certain number of possible combinations and , to the best of my knowledge, current R packages to obtain LaTeX input are mostly designed for tabular outputs.

An alternative approach I was thinking about, could be saving the list object outside of the R environment, then handling it. But I do not have any competence in this kind of tasks.

Please, let me know if there are any possible solutions.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please provide a MWE.

Comment: No. I am unable to accomplish this task.

Comment: If you've tried *anything* at all, can provide it? StackExchange isn't a code-writing service :-(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Your question is not very clear to me. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. At least you could show the desired input style that specifies what you want and how the output should look.  That is, make it a question about LaTeX.  Keep the example small and focused to one question and you shoud get answers fairly quickly here. Help us help you...

Comment: Could you sketch the result you want?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to understand what do you want, but I guess that `knitr` plus `asis` allows you to output a dynamic survey.

In the example below you will have `numRespondents` surveys, each on a separate page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
<<echo=FALSE>>=
vignettes=c("A", "B", "C", "D")
dimensions=c("i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v", "vi") 
vignettesPerRespondent=2
dimensionsPerVignette=3
numRespondents=1 
@ 

<<results='asis',echo=FALSE>>=
for (i in (1:numRespondents)) {
    v <- sample(vignettes, vignettesPerRespondent, replace=FALSE)
    lapply(v, function (vignette) {
        cat ("Consider vignette ", vignette, "\\par\n")
        d <- sample(dimensions, dimensionsPerVignette, 
                    replace=FALSE)
        cat("\\begin{itemize}\n")
        lapply(d, function(dimension) {
            cat ("\\item ", 
                 "Please estimate dimension ", dimension, 
                 "\n")})
        cat("\\end{itemize}\\par\n")

    })
        cat("\\clearpage\n")
}
@ 

\end{document}
```

Using `Rscript -e "library('knitr'); knit('tmp.rnw')"` I get an automatically generated file `tmp.tex` with random entries like this:

```
Consider vignette  D \par
\begin{itemize}
\item  Please estimate dimension  ii 
\item  Please estimate dimension  iv 
\item  Please estimate dimension  i 
\end{itemize}\par
Consider vignette  A \par
\begin{itemize}
\item  Please estimate dimension  i 
\item  Please estimate dimension  v 
\item  Please estimate dimension  ii 
\end{itemize}\par
\clearpage
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Boris, thanks for your suggestions. I did not reply, as all the notifications were in the spam. This is basically what I was looking for: despite the format is far from what I need to have, this is undoubtedly a valuable starting point. Thanks !